# Is it ok to hand off to dev typography specs in this convention and not H1 - H6

Tags: design-patterns, tags, hierarchy, typography

[image]

As a UX/UI designer specific sizes for H1 - H3 cause issues so I prefer to use system shown on the left side of the image. Is this a problem in handoff? It creates much more flexibility.
Thanks

I researched different approaches to typography and style guides(DSM's) to make my approach to design flexible and not locked in. I and wanted developers input.